# Getting error list from scaffolded function in Grails controller template

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm using Grails 1.3.7. In a Grails project, I want to add a function *ajaxupdate* to the default scaffolded Controller, which does exactly the same job as the *update* function, but returns JSON data with the list of the eventual errors.

```
  def ajaxupdate = {
    String retMessage = ""
    List errMessageList = []

    def ${propertyName} = ${className}.get(params.id)
    if (${propertyName}) {
        ${propertyName}.properties = params
        if (!${propertyName}.hasErrors() && ${propertyName}.save(flush: true)) {
            retMessage = "\${message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: '${domainClass.propertyName}.label', default: '${className}'), ${propertyName}.id])}"
        }
        else {
            // Add errors in errMessageList
        }
    }
    else {
        errMessageList.add("\${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: '${domainClass.propertyName}.label', default: '${className}'), params.id])}")
    }

    render(contentType: "text/json") {
        answer(
            message:retMessage,
            errors:errMessageList)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking how to get the errors list, you can access [Errors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) like

```
errMessageList = ${propertyName}.errors.allErrors.collect {g.message(error:it).encodeAsHTML()}
```

Comment: Thanks, Victor ! It does *exactly* what I wish !